# How do you fill a hexagon with triangles in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm currently working on a logo. I wanna fill the hexagon with triangles like in the picture below. How do  I do that?
[image][image]

Comment: What have you attempted so far in order to create this? Please give at least a brief insight into your progress working on this particular problem, so the community can provide you with specific answers for specific questions.

Comment: You'd better do this in Illustrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to think to divide the hexagon by lines which are parallel with the sides of the hexagon. Precise hexagon can initially be created as a vector shape and the dividing lines, too. After creating the hexagon and a couple of lines, you rasterize them to different layers and copy the lines to wanted positions. Then you flatten the image, remove the exessive line ends and floodfill the areas with right colors. You must use a high pixel resolution - much larger than the final output - to avoid any visible defects in the seams. Floodfill easily spread over the narrow borders if you not at first use quick select or polygonal lasso to define the exact area to be filled.

This will be a shattering task in Photoshop because it's not designed for precise making, positioning (=by snapping) and colouring vector objects. You will gain big nerve savings if you start in a vector graphics program like Illustrator.